# Using search string in google Custom search API

Tags: php, google-app-engine, url, google-search-api

Hi all i am using Google Custom search API

```
$search_query = "Amazon+Bestsellers+Rank:+200+in+Health+and+Beauty";
$amazon_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=3425lh43lkh52lk34jh5&cx=023470239740:kj2h3kl4hlk23&alt=atom&num=5&q='$search_query'";
$google_search = file_get_contents($amazon_url);
```

Now my Question is i am searching product with rank 200 in health and beauty, and this does work well but the Amazon department's real name is "Health&Beauty" so i can't use this string because "&" is used as parameter in url and i tried to use `&amp;` but doesn't work so do anyone know how to make it work.
API Key and CX number in url are changed for obvious reason.
--Thank you in advance.

Comment: i tried urlencoding aswell @jprofitt but doesn't work..

Comment: Haha yeah, the markdown engine on here does allow some HTML so you have to either put it in code marks or use HTML encoding

Comment: Thanks mate.. this does works perfectly but i am just bit paranoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode query parameters.